# How Many Hive Dynamic Partitions are Needed?

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I am running a large job that consolidates about 55 streams (tags) of samples (one sample per record) at irregular times over two years into 15-minute averages. There are about 1.1 billion records in 23k streams in the raw dataset, and these 55 streams make up about 33 million of those records.
I calculated a 15-minute index and am grouping by that to get the average value, however I seem to have am exceeded the max dynamic partitions on my hive job in spite of cranking it way up to 20k. I can increase it further I suppose, but it already takes awhile to fail (about 6 hours, although I reduced it to 2 by reducing the number of streams to consider), and I don’t actually know how to calculate how many I really need.

Here is the code:

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true; 
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict; 
SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=50000;
SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=20000; 


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sensor_part_qhr; 

 CREATE TABLE sensor_part_qhr (
    tag  STRING,
    tag0 STRING,
    tag1 STRING,
    tagn_1  STRING,
    tagn  STRING,

    timestamp  STRING,
    unixtime INT,
    qqFr2013 INT,

    quality  INT,
    count  INT,
    stdev  double,
    value    double
)  
PARTITIONED BY (bld STRING);

INSERT INTO TABLE sensor_part_qhr
PARTITION (bld) 
SELECT  tag,
        min(tag), 
        min(tag0), 
        min(tag1), 
        min(tagn_1), 
        min(tagn),

        min(timestamp),
        min(unixtime),  
        qqFr2013,

        min(quality),
    count(value),
    stddev_samp(value), 
        avg(value)
FROM    sensor_part_subset     
WHERE   tag1='Energy'
GROUP BY tag,qqFr2013;
```

And here is the error message:

```
    Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
    Examining task ID: task_1442824943639_0044_m_000008 (and more) from job job_1442824943639_0044
    Examining task ID: task_1442824943639_0044_r_000000 (and more) from job job_1442824943639_0044

    Task with the most failures(4): 
    -----
    Task ID:
      task_1442824943639_0044_r_000000

    URL:
      http://headnodehost:9014/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1442824943639_0044&tipid=task_1442824943639_0044_r_000000
    -----
    Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
    Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveFatalException: [Error 20004]: Fatal error occurred when node tried to create too many dynamic partitions. The maximum number of dynamic partitions is controlled by hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions and hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode. Maximum was set to: 20000
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:283)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
    Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveFatalException:

    [Error 20004]: Fatal error occurred when node tried to create too many dynamic partitions. 
    The maximum number of dynamic partitions is controlled by hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions and hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode. 
    Maximum was set to: 20000

        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.getDynOutPaths(FileSinkOperator.java:747)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.startGroup(FileSinkOperator.java:829)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.defaultStartGroup(Operator.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.startGroup(Operator.java:521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:232)
        ... 7 more

    Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
    Container killed on request. Exit code is 137
    Container exited with a non-zero exit code 137


    FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
    MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
    Job 0: Map: 520  Reduce: 140   Cumulative CPU: 7409.394 sec   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 393345977 SUCCESS
    Job 1: Map: 9  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 87.201 sec   HDFS Read: 393359417 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
    Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 days 2 hours 4 minutes 56 seconds 595 msec
```

Can anyone give some ideas as to how to calculate how many of these dynamic nodes I might need for a job like this?

Or maybe I should be doing this differently?  I am running Hive 0.13 by the way on Azure HDInsight.

**Update:**

- Corrected some of the numbers above.
- Reduced it to 3 streams operating on 211k records and it finally
  succeeded.
- Started experimenting, reduced the partitions per node to 5k, and then 1k, and it still succeeded.

So I am not blocked anymore, but I am thinking I would have needed millions of nodes to do the whole dataset in one go (which is what I really wanted to do).

Comment: Having enormous partitions on Hive will eventually bring your name node down..

Comment: What do you consider enormous? It is about a 0.9 TB database with about 100 partitions, probably the biggest is around 50 GB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic partition columns must be [specified last](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DynamicPartitions) among the columns in the SELECT statement during insertion in sensor_part_qhr.

Comment: Yes, indeed that was it, and I found it and fixed it and never got back to posting it as an answer myself. But thanks and here is your reward :).

Comment: Although if you have a guess as to calculate how many "dynamic nodes" are needed, it would be helpful to add that to your response.

Comment: for very partition, new directory will be created in hadoop hdfs, hence it is advisable not to make too many partitions. We should choose partition column with values that have high one-many ratio with number of rows.